# How to fill out a form from StreamReader in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, streamreader

I am creating a project in Xamarin Forms that allows the user to type in their name, a username, a password, and use a stepper to tell their age and a switch to identify if the user is a student. The user can then hit save, and the information will be saved to a file via StreamWriter. The user will then be able to hit "Load" and all of their saved information will auto-populate the entry boxes, the age value, and the student "true or false" switch.
I am having trouble in the `MainPage.xaml.cs` class with loading the saved information to populate the fields. I have binded the control names in the `MainPage.xaml` to the property values in my `EntryFields` class. This is my first time using Xamarin Forms and I am stuck. Please help :)
Here's what I have for my saved method so far before I got stuck:

```
        {
            List<string> data = new List<string>();
            bool stepValue;
            int ageValue;
            //Read data from file
            if (File.Exists(_fileName))
            {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(_fileName))
                {
                    string line;
                    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        data.Add(line);
                    }
                    
                    for(int i = 0; i < data.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (data[4] == "true")
                        {
                            stepValue = true;
                        }
                        else if (data[4] == "false")
                        {
                            stepValue = false;
                        }
                        ageValue = Int32.Parse(data[3]);
                        //This is where I am stuck. I want to add each item to my list of EntryFields
                        //but I am not sure how since they're all different values.
                    }
                    

                }
            }
            else
            {
                DisplayAlert("Error", "Unable to load. Fill out required information and select SAVE.", "Go Back");
            }


        }
```

Here is my `EntryFields` class that looks like this:

```
    {
        public bool TrueOrFalse { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        
        public string Username { get; set; }

        public string Password { get; set; }

        public int Age { get; set; }

        public EntryFields(string name, string username, string password, int age, string student)
        {
            Name = name;
            Username = username;
            Password = password;
            Age = age;
            if (student.ToLower() == "true")
            {
                TrueOrFalse = true;
            }
            else if(student.ToLower() == "false")
            {
                TrueOrFalse = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Finally, so we are all looking at the same thing, here is my `MainPage.xaml` class:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MorganHall_CE01.MainPage">

    <StackLayout IsVisible="True">
        <Frame BackgroundColor="#2196F3" Padding="24" CornerRadius="0">
            <Label Text="Code Exercise 1" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="White" FontSize="36"/>
        </Frame>
        <Entry x:Name="nameEntry" Placeholder="Enter Name Here" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" TextColor="#514E4E" />
        <Entry x:Name="usernameEntry" Placeholder="Enter Username Here" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Username}" TextColor="#514E4E" />
        <Entry x:Name="passwordEntry" Placeholder="Enter Password Here" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Password}" IsPassword="True" TextColor="#514E4E" />
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10">
            <Label x:Name="ageLabel" Text="Age: " HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="#000000" />
            <Stepper x:Name="ageStepper" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Increment="1" Margin="50,0" Value="{Binding Age}" />
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label x:Name="studentLabel" Text="Enrolled Student: " HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="#000000" />
            <Switch x:Name="studentSwitch" IsToggled="{Binding TrueOrFalse}" Margin="50,0" OnColor="#60E848" ThumbColor="#484453" />
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button x:Name="loadData" Text="Load" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" FontAttributes="Bold" BackgroundColor="#138A83" TextColor="#FDFAFA" />
            <Button x:Name="saveData" Text="Save" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" FontAttributes="Bold" BackgroundColor="#075D7F" TextColor="#FBF8F8" />
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

In the `MainPage.xaml.cs` class, I have a list of ***EntryFields*** that looks like this:
`private List<EntryFields> entries = new List<EntryFields>();`

Please tell me there is a better and easier way to load the saved information. I am all confused.
Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: What specific bit isn't working?

Comment: Have you considered storing the data as JSON instead?

Comment: @mjwills The stream reader won't load my file and replace the entry fields with the saved information. This is an assignment for school and our instructor told us that JSON would work but he didn't want us to use that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this should work

```
var entries = new EntryFields();

// this will read all the file data into a string array
var data = File.ReadAllLines(_fileName);

// you will need to be sure the order matches the order you saved in
entries.Name = data[1];
entries.Username = data[2];
entries.Password = data[3];
entries.Age = int.Parse(data[4]);

// set the binding context of the page
this.BindingContext = entries;
```

Comment: So, I did that and I am getting an error for entries.Age = int.Parse(data[4]);. The error that pops us says that "input string was not in correct format."

Comment: is `data[4]` the line that contains the age field?  Is it a valid int value?  You can use a try/catch block to catch the exception, or `TryParse` instead of `Parse`.  Since you did not post your save code I had to make assumptions about the order in which the fields were saved, YOU need to modify the code to match your actual save.